# Ubuntu boots into command line instead of X

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, x-windows

I posted this on the Ubuntu forums and they had no good answer. I hope you guys have a solution!

> On my relatively new install, it's
>   booting into command line instead of
>   X--again.
>
> This is the reason I reinstalled in
>   the first place. This has happened to
>   me three times now.
>
> So, I boot up and it gets past GRUB,
>   past the glowing Ubuntu option, then
>   it prompts me for my username, then
>   password. I run:
>
> `startx`
>
> And that starts the GUI for about a
>   minute, then it runs the GUI login
>   system.
>
> To add to the mess, the network-applet
>   is not shown in the panel.
>   Additionally, Chrome will not launch
>   (I ran Firefox from the terminal).
>
> What's the problem here?

Comment: "happened before"; it was working correctly for a while, then this started? Did you install a graphics driver perhaps?

Comment: No, nothing. Just normal stuff for about a month, then it started doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious as to what you mean by

> So, I boot up and it gets past GRUB,
>   past the glowing Ubuntu option, then
>   it prompts me for my username, then
>   password. I run:
>
> startx
>
> And that starts the GUI for about a
>   minute, then it runs the GUI login
>   system.

I read this as:

1. I boot
2. I login to terminal
3. I execute startx
4. X starts and I can mess around a bit
5. X gets clobbered by GDM - the GUI login

If so then for some reason GDM is taking a ridiculous amount of time to launch. Could be authentication backend related or just about anything.

In your place I'd start checking the logs :

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
/var/log/auth
/var/log/daemon
/var/log/error
/var/log/syslog
```

At this point we're fishing to try and figure out what's going on on your system.

Comment: Yes, that is the right order.

Nothing odd in the logs, I can attach them, if you'd like.

Comment: Well not terribly useful if there's nothing odd in the logs... -_-
How about starting gdm manually in debug mode to see if the issue is there ? 

1. sudo service gdm stop
2. sudo gdm --debug --timed-exit

Hopefully with that you should either a) find some useful logging information and/or b) determine if GDM is slow to launch or if the slowdown happens before that.

On another note, can you see the output of the startup scripts when you're booting up ? Does it seem to stall or fail somewhere ? 

Are you using networked authentication .. ie ldap ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats the reason. you may want to check logs.

Anyways try this

1. When starting up, in Grub, choose recovery mode
2. It should give a menu list to choose various actions
3. One of the action is setting up X display, try this option.

Comment: Nothing odd in the logs, though I'll try the recovery mode.

Answer (score -1):

If when booting your system it starts ubuntu in Terminal mode, try this:(I suppose you have the latest Ubuntu Karmic Koala)

First: Login via the Terminal(Username & password)

Second: Type:

sudo service gdm start

It should now load the Gnome Display manager with no problems.
If you still encounter problems then find solutions in the Ubuntu Forms.
I know you've try before but, try again.